# ob_end_clean() don't work as intended

Tags: php, buffer

From the PHP manual:

```
ob_end_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer and **turn off** output buffering.
```

The second part is what don't work. 
If i write:

```
echo "a";
ob_end_clean();
echo "b";
```

it should write nothing. The problem is that it print "b". This function should work as i think? 
If yes, is it possible that server disabled the possibility to turn off buffer?

Comment: Buffered or not, if you say "echo" in your PHP script, it's going to output that value. All ob_end_clean() is doing is turning off the buffer and flushing it in one function call.

Comment: Output buffering only buffers what comes *between* ob_start() and ob_end_[...]() calls.  Since echo "b"; comes after your ob_end_clean(), it will be echoed.

Comment: @dtech It's a misuse of  buffering. There are really two ways to output values in PHP, buffered and unbuffered. He's using both in this example, and both are valid. Putting your output in a buffer just means it won't be output immediately. Putting your output outside a buffer means output immediately. As pointed out below, the script will continue execution event after a call to halt the buffer.

Comment: ok i think i understand now. the problem is what he means with "turn off".Thanks

Comment: the buffer is limited? if the data in buffer is very high what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the function.

```
ob_start();
echo 'a';
ob_end_clean();
echo 'b';
```

Would output b.

a is in the buffer so when you erase it that won't be displayed.

ob_end_clean erases the output buffer and turns it off. It doesn't prevent the script from continuing. You could add exit; after ob_end_clean which wouldn't output b.

Comment: buffer is limited? if the data i am buffering is very big what happen?

Comment: It is possible to limit the size of the buffer but most hosts won't do that by default. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php